# Why in HTML tamplate I get extra white space?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I prepare html template and I get an issue. When I open it in gmail I get extra white space. In outlook is works as it should. I believe there needs to be some dependencies added to head but have no idea which one.

This is how it should look like :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And here how it looks in gmail:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
        <title>Reset password email</title>
        <!--[if mso]>
            <noscript>
                <xml>
                    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
                    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml>
            </noscript>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
            table { font-family: 'Poppins';}
        </style>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body
        style="
            background: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            font-family: 'Poppins';
        "
    >
        <table
            align="left"
            cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="0"
            style="
                border: 0;
                background: #ffffff;
                width: 412px !important;
                height: 436px;
            "
        >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 64px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 123px;
                        "
                    >
                        Zapomniałeś hasła ?
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 14px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 313px;
                        "
                    >
                        Aby zresetować hasło, proszę kliknąć w poniższy link:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
 
                            border-radius: 3px;    
                            background-color: #ffffff;
                            display: table-cell;
                            text-align: left;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                        "
                    >
                        <a
                            href="#"
                            style="
                                text-decoration: none;
                                font-weight: 500;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                color: #ffffff;
                                line-height: 30px;
                                background-color: #232835;
                                margin-left: 51px;
                                margin-top: 7px;
                                padding: 6px 36px 6px 36px;
                                border-radius: 3px;
                                letter-spacing: -2%;
                            "
                            >RESETUJ HASŁO</a
                        >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 13px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 316px;
                        "
                    >
                        W razie problemów skontaktuj się z administratorem
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 9px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 54px;
                            width: 140px;
                        "
                    >
                        Imię Nazwisko </br>
                        500 500 500 </br>
                        admin@nevomo.com

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 17px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 84px;
                        "
                    >
                        Pozdrawiamy,
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img
                            src="https://i.ibb.co/YhtGLnf/nevomo-logo-orange.png" alt="nevomo-logo-orange" border="0"
                            style="
                                width: 112.17px;
                                height: 15.74px;
                                padding: 12.13px 0 0 56.41px;
                                color: #eb5d1c;
                            "
                            alt="logo"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 7.6px 0 64px 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 11px !important;
                            line-height: 16.5px;
                            height: 51px;
                            width: 206px;
                        "
                    >
                        ul.Mińska 63A lok.245 </br>
                        03-828 Warszawa </br>
                        www | facebook | instagram | linkedin

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this for sure, but it's very possible that gmail is reading the line breaks in your html and adding line breaks to the email. It's not necessarily the same as a browser that will ignore extra white space. HTML in email acts differently.

So try changing to this (don't add a line break before the closing tag)

```
<td
    style="padding: 7.6px 0 64px 53px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 11px !important;
        line-height: 16.5px;
        height: 51px;
        width: 206px;">
```

or close all the breaks (safest)

```
<td style="padding: 7.6px 0 64px 53px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px !important; line-height: 16.5px; height: 51px; width: 206px;">
```

Use `<br />` when you need line breaks.

Comment: fixed it. I had to change selectors and make each text line in separate <tr> and <td>. Works. I have another issue but I will put next post about it